# Prepare statement return false but insert successfully

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

When I run the prepare statement to insert some data the database, it returns false, however I can see the new row in the database, anyone knows why? I appreciate for any help. And it only happens on INSERT statement.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO BbUsers(u_username,u_passhash,u_emailaddr,u_validate) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
$refArr = array("ssss", $username, $passhash, $email, $vaildHash); 
$result = cleanQuery($query, $refArr);

if ($result2) {
    sendEmail($email, $hash);
} else {
    echo "OOps   something went wrong plz try again";
 exit;
}
```

Here is the function for prepare statement

```
  function cleanQuery($prepareState,$Arrs)
{
    global $dbcon;
    $refArr=array();
    $res=$dbcon->prepare($prepareState);
    $ref= new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
    $method=$ref->getMethod("bind_param"); 
    foreach($Arrs as $key => &$value)
    {$refArr[] = &$value;
    }
    $method->invokeArgs($res,$refArr); 
    $res->execute();
    $result=$res->get_result();
    return $result;
}
```

I tried to get error information from $res and $dbcon, which it returns 0.
Here's db looks like

```
CREATE TABLE BbUsers(
u_userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
u_username CHAR(60) UNIQUE   ,
u_passhash CHAR(100) ,
u_emailaddr CHAR(255) UNIQUE ,
u_created TIMESTAMP ,
u_lastlogin TIMESTAMP ,
u_validate CHAR(40),
INDEX (u_username , u_emailaddr)
);
```

Anything else I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php):

> **mysqli_stmt::get_result**
>
> Returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure. The mysqli_errno() function can be used to distinguish between the two types of failure.

So `$res->get_result()` works only as you expect for `select`.

To check if your prepared statement was executed correctly, you can directly use the return parameter for [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

> **mysqli_stmt::execute**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

You should probably use two different functions, one for `select`-statements that return a result set (that you by the way have to `fetch()`, otherwise further queries won't work, read the note in the [documentation to `execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)), and one for other statements, that return `true` or `false`.

And you obviously have to replace `if ($result2) {` with `if ($result) {`, but I assume that is just a typo.